# What am I doing wrong in this F# code?

Tags: f#, parallel-processing

let parallelTest n = Color(Color.DeepPink, Triangles(sphere n));;

Parallel.For(0,10,new  Action(parallelTest));;

Error message : 
error FS0001: Type mismatch. Expecting a
    int -> unit
but given a
    int -> scene.
The type 'unit' does not match the type 'scene'

I'll glad if some body help me.

Comment: Based on your code and some of your comments, it looks like you're not fully in the groove of F# programming style. Can you post your code and describe what you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 5):

Compose your function with `ignore` to make it return `unit`:

```
Parallel.For(0, 10, parallelTest >> ignore)
```

Comment: Hi Mauricio, thanks for your help too. It works!!!!!!! But now I need to know how can I return a scene type this for? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Parallel.For doesn't return any value. This might help you: http://weblogs.asp.net/podwysocki/archive/2009/02/23/adding-parallel-extensions-to-f.aspx . Create other questions if you have more doubts.

Answer (score 4):

If you want 10 results, perhaps you want

```
[| for i in 0..9 do
       async { return parallelTest i } |]
|> Async.Parallel
|> Async.RunSynchronously
```

This will return an array of 10 scene results.

Answer (score 0):

At which position does this error message occur? (I can't reproduce the error since I don't know the delcarations of some functions you use)

I guess the following: `Parallel.For` expects a `int -> unit` (`Action<int>` in standard .NET), but `parallelTest` has a different type (`int -> scene`) which is therefore incompatible.

And what are you trying to achieve with the whole code?

Comment: Hi Dario, 
thanks for your help, I'm trying to do surface subdvision in parallel, but I try to use this Parallel.For as a mean to make easy my job to do that version in parallel. Do you have any tips for me to do this easily and in parallel? Thanks again.